# Why main thread waits for another thread to finish before proceed?

Tags: java, multithreading

The problem that I am facing in a complex Java application boils down to following: the main thread does not proceeds until the sub-thread is not finished, although I thought that it should. The code that exemplifies the problem is shown below:

```
public class ThreadTest {

        static class MyThread extends Thread{
            public void run(){
                for(double i = 0; i<1; i+=0.01){
                    System.out.println(Math.pow(Math.PI,Math.E)*100.0*i-234.0);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            (new MyThread()).run();
            System.out.println("main thread");
        }
    }
```

When I run this program, I always get the output from MyThread first (independently how many steps are in the cycle), and then I get the message from the main thread. The idea of creating threads is to execute code asynchronously, but here I observe a clearly sync behavour. What do I miss?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you find an answer you like, it is polite to accept it. Sometimes it is worth waiting to see if a better answer appears, but that's up to you.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot! I was confused with start and run actually.

Comment: It is confusing that run() is exposed at all.  Really, Thread shouldn't have a run method and you should have to use a Runnable, which is best practice IMHO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call run(), you are calling the run() method in the current thread!. In the same manner as if you called any other method for another object.

If you want a new thread to call run(), you need to call start() on the thread.

try

```
new MyThread().start();
```

One way to prove this to yourself is to step through your program in a debugger, this would show that the there is only one thread.

Comment: I have no clue but my thread start was in a while loop. I wanted the threads to do their job in the while loop. But somehow, the main program would skip the while loop and that would make the program produce false results. Your answer saved my day.

Comment: answer really solves this issue but its actually does not gives more clear  information about why main waits to finish all other threads.

Comment: @AshishKamble main doesn't wait in whether you use run() or start(). If you use run(), the main thread is calling and running the code in run(), so no waiting occurs. if you call start() another thread is used, and main only waits long enough to trigger the creation of another thread, but not for the thread to run.